# Most efficient way to construct the layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I would have hundreds of such layouts (please see image below), so I need to construct it in most efficient way. There are three areas, two first are aligned by bottom line, left one contains `ImageView`, second one two `TextView`s one under another. There is another view with `TextView` under the second one. Shall I use `TableLayout` as container and `LinearLayout` for the second one? Would it be efficient? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: do you want your text is spread below the image view ?

Comment: No, the TextView on the bottom should not spread below the image view.

Comment: @siik : see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView 1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView 2" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: I don't need the bottom TextView to be spread under ImageView

Answer (score 0):

first sugestion is to make ImageView "taller" so it covers both TextViews in height, or to make bottom TextView wider to cover ImageView and upper TextView..

It would look nicer in my opinion, this empty space is making stabbing pain in my eyes..

Then I would recommend TableLayout and of course this layout in separate file, so u can reuse it with include.. ;)

cheers, hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `RelativeLayout` you should Add `Image View` with `AlignParentLeft="true"` and `alignParenttop = "true"` and then add the first `TextView` as `RightOff` of the imageView and the Second Text view add it to `LayoutBottom` of the First `TextView`

Use `Relative Layouts`, they are considered to be lighter from `Linear Layouts`.

Answer (score 0):

try this , it will exaclty gives you the layout that you've described in your question:

```
    <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <ImageView 
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:src="@drawable/img" />

        <RelativeLayout 
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1">

           <TextView 
              android:id="@+id/txt1"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="textView1" />

          <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/txt2"
             android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="textView1" />
       </RelativeLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bg_l_l"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/bg_l_l"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="chintan"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="khetiya"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/bg_l_l"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="this is extra text and this will not spred under the imageview as you can see."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```